# I am many but one name

Tags: riddle

> See me for I am held in the attraction,
>   protection from your home I've given.
>   Adding resource should you ever reach,
>   come not closer I am possessed of breach.
>   Entwined in myself, I am the right size.
>
> I am many but one name!

Clue:

> Perhaps a clue to answer barter,
>  "Serpentine guards like garter."
>  Answer this and you'll be smarter,
>  If you're looking close, try farther!

Clue 2:

> I overheard one saying nearby, "Oye kopeng, to pochuye ke?"

Comment: https://youtu.be/irQppuVfBcs?t=1m7s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the clues and the answers prior to mine, I believe the answer is:

> the Asteroid Belt

See me for I am held in the attraction,

> The Asteroid Belt is held by the Sun's gravity.

protection from your home I've given.

> If the asteroids weren't in the belt (or otherwise trapped by gravity), they'd probably go smash into other planets -- Earth being one of them.

Adding resource should you ever reach,

> Valuable ore or elements within the asteroids could make asteroid mining a prosperous venture...if you can get there. Could also refer to a generic utility *belt*.

come not closer I am possessed of breach.

> Could refer to the danger of smashing into an asteroid.

Entwined in myself, I am the right size.

> This seems to relate more to a generic *belt* being sized to a person's waist, though it could also refer to the Belt's position between Mars and Jupiter.

I am many but one name!

> Many asteroids, one Asteroid Belt.

Answer (score 7):

it is a

> **bar**

See me for I am held in the attraction,

> a **bar** keeps you from falling out of the rollercoaster

protection from your home I've given.

> **barring** the door for protection

Adding resource should you ever reach,

> gold **bar** (?)

come not closer I am possessed of breach.

> the letters of **bar** are in breach

Entwined in myself, I am the right size.

> a **bra**, which is **bar** entwined

I am many but one name!

> **bar**

Comment: very nice, but bar does not protect _from_ your home, and a few other differences

Comment: with "protect from your home", do you mean "protecting you from a location (i.e. your home)" or "protection your home itself"? (english is not my mothertongue and I cannot determine which of the two you mean)

Answer (score 4):

You might be:

> Space

See me for I am held in the attraction

> The first letters of each line of this puzzle spell SPACE

protection from your home I've given

> not sure how this one fits

Adding resource should you ever reach

> If mankind makes it far out enough into outer space, there are supposed to be lots of mine-able metals and resources we can use.

come not closer I am possessed of breach

> I'm guessing this is a reference to personal space?

Entwined in myself, I am the right size

> Space contains space, and... well, whatever size it might be is enough to contain itself, so that's right.

I am many but one name

> People have a lot of terms for (outer) space, but at the end its just... space.

To be fair I think @Meta45 has a much better answer, just thought I'd give it a shot.

Comment: on the right track

Comment: "protection from your home I've given" - I imagine the home is talking about our planet Earth, suspended in space, but not sure it means our planet has protection from space in the form of our atmosphere (in which case the puzzle might be phrased incorrectly) or if it literally means that space is protected FROM our earth by the forces that make it difficult to escape such as gravity?

Comment: "I am many but one name" - you can have lots of spaces, but collectively it is just "space".

Answer (score 2):

**New answer from the hint:**

> The solar System.

Just a random guess from @Joe answer's that is it-

> Constellation.

See me for I am held in the attraction,

> A constellation is a group of stars that are considered to form imaginary outlines or meaningful patterns on the celestial sphere, typically representing animals, mythological people or gods, mythological creatures, or manufactured devices. So, we can see them as they are held as attraction.

Protection from your home I've given

> Not sure about the second line , but maybe many superstitious are related to them some consider doing all the jobs according to them, so as to get safety and prosperity for them and their family.

Adding resource should you ever reach

> ?

Come not closer, I am possessed of breach

> people can't go any closer to them they can just study them from here using telescope.

Entwined in myself, I am the right size

> ?

I am many but one name

> They are many but fall under the category of constellations .

Comment: Closer... closer

Answer (score 0):

I think you are:

> A Star!

See me for I am held in the attraction

> Stars are in space, which is what is spelled in the first letter of each line

Protection from your home I've given

> When young children are troubled, they often wish upon stars. This is especially true if there are issues at home.

Adding resource should you ever reach

> If we ever reach another star, we'll gain a lot of natural resources (hydrogen, helium, whatever metals make up that solar system).

Come not closer, I am possessed of breach

> Breach is defined as a broken, ruptured, or torn condition or area. Could this refer to a [sunspot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunspot)?

Entwined in myself, I am the right size

> Is this referring to a binary star system?

I am many but one name

> There are many stars, but they're all just called stars.

Hint: "Serpentine guards like garter."

> Here is the main reason I think it is a star. Each line in your clue ends in "ter", and when I think of serpentine, I think of an s. So "ster" or star.

Comment: Very close @Joe-You-Know  but not quite right...

Comment: @jmb.mage if this answer is very close is it the "pole star"

Answer (score 0):

You are:

> The Sun

See me for I am held in the attraction

> The sun is in space, which is what is spelled in the first letter of each line

Protection from your home I've given

> without the sun there wouldn't even be life on earth

Adding resource should you ever reach

> plants photosynthesize with sun rays

Come not closer, I am possessed of breach

> sunspot